# How do I do a WHERE on the COUNT(name) produced by a GROUP BY clause?

Tags: sql

WHERE gets processed before GROUP BY in the SELECT statement.  How can I use WHERE on the result of a COUNT(name)?

What I want is this:

```
SELECT topic, COUNT(name) AS counter
FROM blah
GROUP BY name
WHERE counter <> 1
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
SELECT topic, COUNT(name) AS counter
FROM blah
GROUP BY topic
HAVING COUNT(name) <> 1
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `GROUP BY topic`?

Answer (score 7):

I think you are looking for Having Clause:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx

```
SELECT topic, COUNT(name) AS counter
FROM blah
GROUP BY topic
HAVING COUNT(name) <> 1
```

Answer (score 3):

as the other have answered you need a HAVING.

`WHERE` filters the rows remaining after all joins

`GROUP BY` combines rows into groups

`HAVING` filters those groups

don't worry abut repeating the COUNT(*) in the SELECT list and the having, the optimizer is smart enough to optimize this of most databases